# Is it possible to create a brushed metal material in the standard blender render?

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

Is it possible to create a brushed metal material in the standard blender render? 
I need to create concentric brushed metal. Something like that https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS-ZenBook-UX330UA/
I know that this can be done with Cycle, but I am still very uncomfortable with it.
Maybe I might use some kind of imitation or something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my first post here, and I apologize if I do something wrong.

Comment: I would recommend just using cycles render. It is much nicer. You could probably fake the effect with a texture in the blender render though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I think that in the end I will move to the Cycles. But till now I have not achieved good results with it. That certainly is my fault. And I just do not have a good texture for it.

Comment: There is anisotropy in BI which is what you would need, but Cycles is way better. If you don't have good textures for Cycles, then you don't have good textures for BI either. I would suggest [textures.com](http://www.textures.com/) for high-quality, free textures, or [search for pre-made materials](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=brushed+metal+material+cycles&t=ffab&atb=v45-6&ia=web). Here is a good tutorial on [brushed metal in Cycles](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-anisotropic-shading/).

Comment: 10 Replies, pycoder, Thank you very much for your help!
I will try to use cycles.
And a special thank you for the useful links. I sorry, I had to create another account to write it.